# regular expression for link

Tags: javascript, regex

i need to trim this string ->  http://hokuspokus/ixdebude/ix and i exactly Need this part of the string  **/ixdebude/ix**

I have 2 expressions to solve my Problem.

My first regex ->

`/(.*)\/(.*)(\/)(.*)\/*/g` returns Array[5] groups .

my second regex ->

`/(\/............)$(.*?)$/g` returns **/ixdebude/ix**

Can someone of you give me another regex, a better without thousand dots ?

Comment: Why not just use `split`?

Comment: Additionally - that link / string is not a valid URL.  If your regex needs to support valid URL's, you might want to address that.  Also - what is special about the `ixdebude/ix` part?  Is it the first part after the domain name? Or something else?

Comment: Do you know what the domain name is in advance? That will make it trivial and not require any regex.

Comment: Also - you should see this question / answer.  Your first regex may do what you want IF you understand how to access the information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression?rq=1

Comment: @cale_b well, the first part could be valid. imagine `localhost/mypage.html` - as long as DNS resolves it, it can be a link

Comment: This is a very confusing question.  Literally you can use `"http://hokuspokus/ixdebude/ix".match(/\/ixdebude\/ix/)`.  It would be helpful to know more than one case you need to match against. Is it always two segments and always at the end? Then you can use `/\/[^/]+\/[^/]+$/`.  Is it always immediately after a url?  Is there more than one match in a single string possible?

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regex like this:

```
//.*?(/.*)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oQ5xZ6/1)**

For javascript, you could use:

```
var re = /\/\/.*?(\/.*)/; 
var str = 'http://hokuspokus/ixdebude/ix';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try this

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```

https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

Comment: Yeah, not mine sadly. Credit goes to - https://gist.github.com/jlong. Just put the code here incase it ever gets deleted.