# Split Link and Insert into the Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my site I have a HTML form like the following:

```
<label>Name</lable>
<input name="username" id="username19" type="text" value="">
```

and let's say that the link in the address bar of the browser is:

> https://sitename.com/consulting/order-plan/#ref/testing**

I want to do following thing:

Pick the URL from the browser address bar and split it by "/". After choose the last word in this case it's "testing" and insert it to the form value with the ID "username19"

Could you help me to do this with Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619951/regular-expression-for-link/39620022#39620022

Comment: Are you going to bind it to an event, like click or sth? Or right after the document load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `document.URL` to get current url and get last word with regex

```js
var url = document.URL;
var match = url.match(/([^/]*)$/);

console.log(url);
console.log(match);

document.getElementById("username19").value = match[1];
```

```html
<label for="username19" >Name</lable>
<input name="username" id="username19" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks friend, you were very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You could get the current path from the address bar using `window.location.pathname` then split it using `substr` and finally get the last part using `lastIndexOf('/')` like :

```
var current_path_name = window.location.pathname
console.log( current_path_name.substr(current_path_name.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) );
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try like as -

**JavaScript :**

```
function ReplaceHash(){
    var url       = window.location.pathname;      /*URL without HASH*/
    var hash      = window.location.hash;          /*Only Hash URL*/
    var lastWord  = hash.split('/');
    lastWord[(lastWord.length)-1] = 'username19';  /*Put your text here*/
    hash          = lastWord.join('/');
    url           = url + hash;                    /*Your New URL*/
    return url;
}

var newUrl = ReplaceHash();
console.log(newUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

This loads after input element is loaded. But you can bind it to an event.

```js
$('input').load('input', function () {
  var str = window.location.pathname.split("/");         
  var res = str[str.length-1];
  document.getElementById("username19").setAttribute("value", res);
  console.log(res);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Name</lable>
<input name="username" id="username19" type="text" value="">
```