# Get specific part of a URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript, I need help solving a problem.

I have the following URL:

`http://localhost/solo04/index.php?route=checkout/checkout#shipping-method`

I would like to just get that part of the url (route =checkout/checkout) how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619951/regular-expression-for-link/39620022#39620022

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use a `regex` or `split`:

```
url = "http://localhost/solo04/index.php?Route=checkout/checkout#shipping-method";

lastPart = url.split('?')[1]; // grabs the part on the right of the ?

console.log(lastPart);
```

More variants are listed [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to throw this out too cause I don't think it's been mentioned here.
You can use the new [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) API too to avoid any `regex` or any string manipulation that I'm seeing on some of the answers here.

But this is relatively new so support for this in older browsers might be limited.

e.g:

```
var myURL = new URL('http://localhost/solo04/index.php?q=somequery');
console.log(myURL);
```

That will give you an object which should have `path`, `hostname`, `search` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hyperlink element to accomplish this, simply create it like you normally would but don't append it to the DOM:

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```

If you then require the query-string, you can parse it using something like:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
}
```

In order to get a specific variable.

Credit to jlong & Tarik for the excellent ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var str1 = "http: //localhost/solo04/index.php? Route = checkout / checkout # shipping-method";
    var n = str1.lastIndexOf("?")+1;
    alert(str1.substr(n));
```